# How do I deserialize a JSON object onto an implementation of an interface based on its key-value pairs?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I am setting up a controller for a Spring Boot application. I want the controller to produce an instance of an implementation of an interface based on the key-value pairs of the incoming JSON string.

The interface:

```
public interface ShoppableItem {}
```

Implementation 1:

```
public class GroceryItem implements ShoppableItem {

@JsonProperty("transactionId")
private Long transactionId;

@JsonProperty
@NotNull
private String itemName;

@JsonProperty
@NotNull
private Float weight;
}
```

Implementation 2:

```
public class ClothingItem implements ShoppableItem {

@JsonProperty("transactionId")
private Long transactionId;

@JsonProperty
@NotNull
private String itemName;

}
```

(Note: If a weight is provided, it is a grocery item and it cannot be null or "". If a weight is not provided, then it is a clothing item).

Controller

```
@Controller
public class Total {

  @PostMapping(value = "total")
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
  public String tester(@Valid @RequestBody ShoppableItem shoppableItem) {
    return shoppableItem.toString();
  }
}
```

JSON body

```
{
"transactionId" : "123",
"itemName" : "whatever"
}
```

The desired result was to create an instance of type ClothingItem. When I tried doing this, I get the following exception:

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of com.test.controllers.Models.ShoppableItem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.test.controllers.Models.ShoppableItem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information

Is this a feature I am implementing incorrectly? I understand this may not be the best approach, as it would be easier to just create 2 endpoints to handle each case.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a static factory method
(annotated with [`@JsonCreator`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html)) to your `ShoppableItem` Interface.
Note that you need to annotate all of its arguments with `@JsonProperty`
so that Jackson will know how to map the JSON properties to method arguments.

```
public interface ShoppableItem {

    @JsonCreator
    public static ShoppableItem create(@JsonProperty("transactionId") Long transactionId,
                                       @JsonProperty("itemName") String itemName,
                                       @JsonProperty("weight") Float weight) {
        if (weight == null)
            return new ClothingItem(transactionId, itemName);
        else
            return new GroceryItem(transactionId, itemName, weight);
    }
}
```

Then Jackson will use that method when deserializing a `ShoppableItem`.